# Modify SQL Query Order By Date (Date filed stored as varchar(25) DD-MMM-YYYY 00:00:00)

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
$sqlC = "SELECT id, con_number, arr_date, arr_flag, reg FROM con WHERE arr_flag=0 AND reg='".$region."' ORDER BY arr_date DESC";
```

Column arr_date stored as varchar(25) example 18-Jun-2007 00:00:00 (sometimes can be empty)

The current query displays all matching records, but the ORDER BY is not working, as it sorts by the first 2 digits (day). For example:
31-Aug-2021 10:06:24
30-Aug-2021 09:14:40
29-Jun-2021 06:24:47
28-May-2021 15:08:30
26-Aug-2021 08:14:54

I'm trying to change this query to have the DESC working correctly, is it possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Joseph

Comment: Your database schema is broken, store dates a real dates, not as strings. Then your query will run correctly as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema is, shall we say, sub-optimal. An ideal fix would be to correct it to store the date/time vales in a DATETIME column, but mindful of your comments about other scripts, the solution for your query is to convert the text value on the fly:

```
SELECT id, con_number, arr_date, arr_flag, reg 
FROM con 
WHERE arr_flag=0 
  AND reg='".$region."' 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(arr_date, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your date is not stored as a date.  You can fix this.  First change the format to an accepted format:

```
update con
    set arr_date = str_to_date(arr_date, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s');

alter table con modify column arr_date datetime;
```

You can also use the expression for ordering, but it is better to fix the data.

Comment: I can't modify the table, the current system has way to many scripts that do updates on this table, I'm looking for a way to modify only the current sort query if this is possible without altering the table

Comment: Then you just need to use his solution above inside your query like so: $sqlC = "SELECT id, con_number, str_to_date(arr_date, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i:%s') as arr_date, arr_flag, reg FROM con WHERE arr_flag=0 AND reg='".$region."' ORDER BY arr_date DESC";

Comment: @SenorCardgage that's exactly what I was looking for, GordonLinoff answer combined with your sample did the trick, much appreciated